# Create dll from ios library

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have several libraries created in Xamarin IOS on mac (don't use Visual Studio). I want to create the libraries is in a Dlls of this project. How can i do it.

Comment: What are you talking about?  A DLL is a .NET library.  Please re-phrase your question so that it's comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

When building a ios library too release it will creates a dll in the bin folder